# how to download the pdf files, showing progressbar with current status in UITableViewCell in iPhone

Tags: ios, download

I want to download pdf file from the internet using my custom web browser and if selected link have the pdf file then it start downloading and also show the full size of file and how much its downloaded must be shown in progress bar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should try AFNetworking

[File Upload with Progress Callback](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking#file-upload-with-progress-callback)